# Weird strange letters appeared in all website links

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, links

I have an issue with my new wordpress website running WooCommerce plugin.

There is a random letters added in all website links “?v=d3d4c5deb455”

I tried deactivating the addon’s and it didn't work - only the letters disappeared when I deactivate “WooCommerce” plugin ... which i cant really deactivated cause it an online store

I tried changing the theam and went back the default template  also it didn't work

Screenshot
https://www.ienajah.com/up/do.php?img=1171
Website : knzshop.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has to do with geolocation, and is functionality built into Woocommerce.

https://woocommerce.wordpress.com/2015/07/02/making-geolocation-static-cache-friendly-in-2-4/

See under the title on that page `Geolocation, with a hint of Ajax`

This seems to be a pretty good write-up of the functionality and how to disable it:

https://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-remove-vxxxx-string-from-wordpress-urls/

Comment: thanks it defiantly helped me